# RPi ssh connection issue through Android smartphone

Tags: wifi, ssh, windows, android

Recently I installed headless Debian/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64 on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, and I'm having problems with SSH. The issue is that I use the German mobile operator Freenet and I can't have a home internet connection, so my Redmi Note 8 Pro is my router for my laptop and RPi. Sometimes I connect to the internet using my smartphone but as a USB modem to increase speed, but as I realized from the output of the command on Termux

```
 ip neigh
```

it's still one local network.

But apparently, my Windows 11 laptop does not see the Raspberry Pi or even Redmi Note 8 on the same network.

I installed IPNeighborsView on Windows 11 and in the table, I only saw my Realtek network adapter and even scanning in Zenmap didn't give me anything.

So I can't connect via ssh through the console and I can't connect via Putty either. The error

```
 port 22: Connection timed out
```

But on my Redmi I have Termux and I connect via SSH to RPi without any problems. I have tried several things:

1. Turn off or reset the firewall on Windows 11.
2. Configured Sharing in Network Adapter Properties menu, but it still turns itself off over time.
3. I installed [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) on RPi but due to the low quality of the connection I ngrok fits poorly. As I understand it works as it tunnels connections over the internet to addresses like *.tcp.eu.ngrok.io and can even do https.

I also tried to [reset all DNS settings on Windows 11](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/dns_probe_started/) , as I started having connectivity issues on my laptop after changing firewall and network adapter settings.

I was able to connect with Windows 11 only once before I changed my SSID and password in Hotspot Redmi, and once after that, but with the Sharing option already set up for network adapters.

*Update: I also managed to accidentally connect to the RPi from a laptop running Windows 11 via a Wi-Fi network after I temporarily disconnected the RPi from the power source and after this, I got a new IP for RPi. But after some time of working on the laptop, I lost the Wi-Fi connection and had to restart it on the smartphone, after which I also lost the ability to connect to the SSH again. Maybe a static IP will solve this problem?*

Comment: Now I connected the RPi via Ethernet and did the Sharing option under Windows 11 Network Adapter Settings and of course I saw the RPi in IPNeighborsView before that. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work over Wi-Fi.

Comment: Have you tried pinging the Pi from Windows using its IP address?  BTW, if you have information to add to your question, please edit it into the question rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Yes, of course, if the ssh connection can reach RPi, then I can see ping from it and a device in the IPNeighborsView table. In other case I get "Request timed out" error.